# I ran an unistall.exe in /Program Files. It marked the entire folder for deletion. How do I prevent that?

Tags: windows, uninstall

This is a bit of an emergency. I accidentally installed a program in the Program Files folder without it creating a subfolder. So I went to uninstall and reinstall by running the "uninstall.exe" file that came with the program. I clicked through it too quickly and after it started uninstalling, I realized that it was uninstalling all the files in the entire folder, and it said "to be deleted on restart". I closed it in Task Manager because there was no cancel button. Now how can I make sure that if I restart my computer I wont lose half my program files folder. I'm running Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

All the commands to delete or rename files at boot are stored in the
registry under the key:
`HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager`
in a multi-valued item named `PendingFileRenameOperations`.

Deleting the item `PendingFileRenameOperations` will abort all boot
delete operations and save your files.

You will however keep the files that were installed into Program Files
by that uninstaller, so you will have to locate them and delete them
yourself.

Comment: Also, to be safe, *copy the Program Files* to another location, so you can at least restore the files, if not any Registry changes made during their original installation.